# How do I cut a flap using edges or vertices

Tags: mesh, edges

Lets take a simple example of a cube.

I want to cut open one of the face of the cube from its three edges but let the third edge connected so that it looks like a flap.

In a more detailed example:

I got a airplane model 
[image]

I want to cut the cockpit windshield along the selected edges in the following photo , please I don't want to completely cut it out but to let some edges attached to main mesh
 [image]

Comment: You are looking for `v` rip edge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using the *Rip* tool. Go into edit mode, select and edge or a selection of edges (or a group of vertices):

[image: SelectEdge]

Now press <kbd>V</kbd>. You will now get something like this:

[image: RippedEdge]

For your specific instance **do not select the shown edges**.

[image]

Every edge is made from two vertices, one on each end. When you rip them, those vertices separate from the mesh, and a new edge is created. However the vertices at the end connect to the mesh still. In your example, pressing <kbd>V</kbd> would make there be a single vertex connecting the two parts, instead of two edges. Use the suggested selection to get the desire result.

Comment: what If I want to cut more than one edge?

Comment: select more than one edge :)

Comment: unfortunately I cannot get it to work as intended, if I select just one edge and press V it also cuts other edges which share the vertices of the selected edge. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Like in [this image] (http://i.gyazo.com/1675c388d27d12648e762dbae92cbc51.png) ripping only the edge shown in white also rips the edges shown in orange

Comment: @user1062760 You are ripping *Vertices*, which are connected by edges. Selecting an edge tells Blender which vertices to rip. Think of it that way.

Comment: but -b b but I wanted to rip only edges :(

Comment: An edge is the line segment connecting two vertices, so having two vertices means there is an edge . . .

Comment: @user1062760 That is laterally imposible due to the way meshes work, unless you want to duplicate edges sitting on top of each other.

Comment: @user1062760 I added a diagram of exactly what your issue was as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "edge split" tool in the "edge" menu that does just that. Select all the canopy edges and split them, and Bob will be your uncle.

However, if you do that, you will end up with duplicate edges around the canopy, which will be difficult to handle.
First you will need to be in face mode to make sure you select the proper ones (i.e the ones tied to the aircraft or the ones tied to the canopy)
Second, to animate the canopy you will need to rotate all these edges along the hinge, which is pretty awkward to do.

I think it would be easier to separate the canopy from the airframe and then rotate it around the hinge (as a separate object) to open and close it.