# Faces left behind when I move a face back

Tags: faces

This is probably one of the easiest things in blender, but I am a plain beginner and can't find any way to solve this. When I select a face and move it back in, the "faces" outside it stay. Not 100% sure how to describe it so I got a picture below.
[image]

Is there something like a "separate" function? opposite of merge?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24369/2843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Mesh-Ripping tool activated with <kbd>V</kbd>.

[image: Example]
Make sure, your mouse cursor is below the vertex (left picture)

You can rip complete Edges as well.

[image: Edge ripping]